# Address returning null using LocationManager and GeoCoder

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I'm simply trying to grab the users location (most accurate way, I assume GPS) - and convert the latittude/longitutde into an address to display in a EditText. I keep getting "null - UnitedStates - US - 06705" basedd off my coordinates. Any idea? Here is my code:

```
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        providers = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providers, 5000,0, this);
```

onLocationChanged method

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null)
        {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Log.i(mTAG, String.valueOf(latitude));

            try {
                 geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);

                 addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                 if (geoCoder.isPresent()) {


                 Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                 String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                 String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                 String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                 String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                 str.append(localityString + " - ");
                 str.append(city + " - " + region_code + " - ");
                 str.append(zipcode);

                 addressTxtField.setText(str);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: are you testing this on emulator?

Comment: No, device. Would I have to define somewhere to use GPS as provider?

Comment: no . it is up to you. your code say get the best provider available to get location coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

you are requesting here last known location. this is a location if any other app request location. if no app request location coordinates then it will return null. you have to make request `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates.`

try this in code :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000,0, this);
```

implements `android.location.LocationListener` interface and then override only location changed method.

```
//called when user location changed
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myLocation = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(),arg0.getLongitude());
        Log.d("location","in location changed");
    }
```

Comment: Updated code, now nothing happens for a good while, then all of a sudden it keeps spamming toast? Nothing showing up in Log though either

Comment: change   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000,0, this);  to   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providers, 5000,0, this);

Comment: why you change providers to LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Comment: Because it was still coming up 'null' and I was trying something new, updated code - still comes up null. And I notice a slight delay in it even displaying, I believe moving my phone triggers it to update - is onLocationChanged even called initially in the first bit of code? Or only when the phones location changes?

Comment: i have made request like give me location after every 5 seconds. so it will make request location updates every 5 seconde.

Comment: Oh, I am trying to just have it make one not keep doing so, how would I accomplish just once? Also any idea why the address turns up null? Would another way around it be to simply use googles api to convert geocode into address?